# mongodb php multi group stage

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to execute below mongodb script using php:

```
db.getCollection('play_history').aggregate(
[ { $match : { At : {$gte : 1470307490, $lt : 1470307497649}, moneyType:1  } } ,
 {
   $group:
     {
       _id: { gameType: "$gameType", sessionId: "$sessionId"},           
     }
 },
 {
   $group:
     {
       _id: "$_id.gameType",
       count: { $sum: 1} 
     }
 }
])
```

Below is the php snip code:

```
$match = [ 'moneyType' => 1, 
        'At' => ['$gt' => 12, '$lt' => 1470307497649]];

$command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command([
    'aggregate' => 'play_history',
    'pipeline' => [
        ['$match' => $match],
        ['$group' => 
            ['_id' => ["gameType" => '$gameType', "sessionId" => '$sessionId']]], 
        ['$group' => 
            ['_id' => '$_id.gameType' ], 
            'countGame' => ['$sum' =>  1 ]],    
    ],
    'cursor' => new stdClass,
]);

$cursor = $manager->executeCommand('falcon', $command);
```

The above code give me the following error:

> A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field

I have tried to change several grouping orders but it didn't work. Is that a limitation of PHP to just has only one group stage per command?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I've edited and formatted your code a bit differently. For formatting, Errors/Exceptions are recommended to be put in block quotes so they stand out. Please don't include your question with unnecessary lines. We do not need to know you're new, or be given thanks ([They clutter the post, and hurt readability.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/295637)). You've mentioned "I have tried to change several grouping orders but it didn't work.", but I see you didn't post them. Including what you've tried helps us help you (As we can comment on why it may not have worked).